# How to use getElementsByTagName with <td> with overflow: hidden on VBA?

Tags: html, excel, vba, get, element

I am using the VBA automation to get some informations of a ticket system in my job. I am trying to get the value into the generated table but only information that doest'go to the column "A" on sheet "Plan1" is `<td>` which contains the overflow: hidden CSS atribute. I don't know if are them related but coincidently are the only data that don't appears. Someone can help me?

HTML code:

```
<div id="posicionamentoContent">
  <table class="grid">
  <thead>...</thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr id="937712" class="gridrow">
         <td width="200px"> Leonardo Peixoto </td>
         <td width="200px"> 23/12/2015 09:45 </td>
         <td width="200px"> SIM </td>
         <td width="200px"> Telhado da loja com pontos de vazamento.</td>
         <td width="200px" align="center"></td>
         <td width="200px" align="center"></td>
     </tr>
...
...
...
```

The complete code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BsFo.png

I need to get the first 4 `<td>` text ( Leonardo Peixoto, 23/12/2015 09:45, SIM and Telhado da loja com pontos de vazamento.) but they are only texts which I can't get.

Obs: When I use developers tools (f12) to inspect each element, it shows me perfectly the information I need inside `<td>`. But when I open "source code" page to checkthe html, the code is like this:

```
<div id="tabPosicionamento" style="padding: 5px 0 5px 0;"  class="ui-tabs-hide">
    div id="posicionamentoContent"></div>
</div>
```

Example VBA:

```
    Sub extractTablesData1()
     'we define the essential variables

     Dim IE As Object, obj As Object
     Dim ticket As String


     Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

     ticket= InputBox("Enter the ticket code")

    With IE

     .Visible = False
     .navigate ("https://www.example.com/details/") & ticket


     While IE.ReadyState <> 4
     DoEvents
     Wend

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan1").Range("A1:K500").ClearContents

    Set data = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("thead")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")

            i = 0
            For Each elemCollection In data
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan1").Range("A" & i + 1) = data(i).innerText
            i = i + 1

            Next elemCollection

End With

IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing

....

....

End Sub
```

This function returns in column **"A"** of sheet **Plan1** only `<td class=info3"></td>` and `<td class=info4"></td>` but I need `<td class=info1"></td>` and `<td class=info2 also."></td>`

Comment: should thead be details instead?

Comment: What is `dados` here?

Comment: Hi, I updated the informations with more details and fix the wrong information about "dados".

Comment: Someone has any answer?

Comment: From your html sample data selection should be IE.document.getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).getElementsbyTagName("td")

Comment: I tried this, but unique information that appears on sheet is <td width="200px" align="center"></td> and <td width="200px" align="center"></td> because the others owns the overflow hidden I think.

Comment: Try debug.print IE.document.getElementsByTagName("tr").innerHTML and see what you get.

Comment: Don't happens anything.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to read the page code due the proxy blocking me, but I faced a similar issue a while ago and the solution I found out was put all data on clipboard and paste. After that I clean the data on the sheet.

Here the code I used to do that:

```
Set ieTable = ie.document.getElementById("ID")
            If Not ieTable Is Nothing Then
                Set clip = New DataObject
                clip.SetText "<html>" & ieTable.outerHTML & "</html>"
                clip.PutInClipboard
                Sheet1.Range("A1").Select
                ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode Text", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
            End If
```

Considering that you need to isolate the 4 td lines, you can do that with a loop for every search.

Comment: Hi Felipe, could you adapt it into my code? I tried to do this but isn't worked. Thanks.

Comment: You only need to put the ID here: Set ieTable = ie.document.getElementById(**"ID"**) and try it. The last line before **end if** will paste on sheet1 then u will only need clean up the data.

Comment: Enjoing your great help, would you know how do I to ignorate the certificate error that appears on Internet Explorer 8? It is preventing that this script don't work in some pc's in my job. Is it possíble to to this directly into the code?

Answer (score 0):

In your sample it numerates the Data, but not using it.  Also, the cell assignment should be cells(x,y).value.  Here is the working code.

```
Sub extractTablesData1()
    'we define the essential variables

    Dim IE As Object, Data As Object
    Dim ticket As String


    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .navigate ("put your data url here")


        While IE.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend

        Set Data = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")

        i = 1
        For Each elemCollection In Data
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, i).Value = elemCollection.innerHTML
            i = i + 1
        Next elemCollection

    End With

    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't bring the information what I need (lasts `<td>`)

```
<div id="posicionamentoContent">
  <table class="grid">
  <thead>...</thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr id="937712" class="gridrow">
         <td width="200px"> Leonardo Peixoto </td>
         <td width="200px"> 23/12/2015 09:45 </td>
         <td width="200px"> SIM </td>
         <td width="200px"> Telhado da loja com pontos de vazamento.</td>
         <td width="200px" align="center"></td>
         <td width="200px" align="center"></td>
     </tr>
```